# GroupManager Groups and perms work in all worlds, how do I stop this?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have set groups and permissions on my server using GroupManager. When I create new worlds with Multiworld or Multiverse, the groups and permissions carry over to these newly created worlds.

How do I make it to so these settings don't carry over to the worlds created with Multiworld/Multiverse?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by editing your Group Manager configuration settings. Navigate to `config.yml` in your `plugin/GroupManager/` directory.

In the `mirrors` section, you can setup configuration for `all_unnamed_worlds`. Any new worlds that get generated by the Multiverse plugin will fall under this category until otherwise specified.

Here's the annotated version of this configuration section [in the documentation](http://wiki.ess3.net/wiki/Group_Manager/Config):

```
mirrors:
        # Worlds listed here have their settings mirrored in their children.
        # The first element 'world' is the main worlds name, and is the parent world.
        # subsequent elements 'world_nether' and 'world_the_end' are worlds which will use
        # the same user/groups files as the parent.
        # the element 'all_unnamed_worlds' specifies all worlds that aren't listed, and automatically mirrors them to it's parent.
        # Each child world can be configured to mirror the 'groups', 'users' or both files from its parent.
        world:
          world_nether:
          - users
          - groups
          world_the_end:
          - users
          - groups
          all_unnamed_worlds:
          - users
          - groups
    #  world2:      (World2 would have it's own set of user and groups files)
    #    world3:
    #    - users    (World3 would use the users.yml from world2, but it's own groups.yml)
    #    world4:
    #    - groups   (World4 would use the groups.yml from world2, but it's own users.yml)
    #  world5:
    #    - world6   (this would cause world6 to mirror both files from world5)
```

So you can either have all your new worlds inherit the `groups.yml` and `users.yml` from another world or define their own unique configurations entirely. This is really up to you how this is done.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a bit of an amature, so what am I supposed to do to make it work?..

Comment: This is a super simple process of just editing a text file. What worlds currently have the permissions you want your new worlds to have?

Comment: the all_unnamed_worlds one, I think thats the answer I need to give, sorry, just really new to this.

Comment: Your question asks "how do I make sure these settings don't carry over?" Out of the list of worlds currently on your server, which one(s) have the "default" settings? Do you want new worlds to have the same permissions as `world`? `spawn`? One you determine which world future worlds will inherit permissions from, put `all_unnamed_worlds` under it in the configuration file. Does that make sense?

Comment: ooooh ok, yes, Thank you, also, in the config file, if I just want to make a completely new world, what do I do? or can I do that

Comment: You can directly assign it permissions by giving it a world label in the config. Or, if you don't list it explicitly, it will fall under `all_unnamed_worlds`. If you put `all_unnamed_worlds` such that it isn't listed under anything else, every new world you create will have a unique set of permissions.

Comment: I think I understand, Thanks so much, you've been a big help :D

Comment: Oh, one more questions, do I remove the words in parenthasis

Comment: Not a problem! Glad to help! Comment if you have any other questions!

Comment: Do I remove the words in parenthesis?

Comment: Yes, it will break if you don't. Also note the `#` is a comment character that will cause the line to be ignored. Make sure everything is indented correctly!